# How to get version (major.minor.patch) numbers from source code on TFS CI tasks

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, nuget, nuget-package, semantic-versioning

I am trying to create a nuget package in ci process. I want to version packages accoring to Semantic versioning. Basically, they will have major.minor.patch-ci-date.

for this puspose, I use nuget packager task on TFS.

[image]

I can configure version on the nuget packager task as shown red frame below. But, there is a problem. Major.minor.patch numbers are decided by the developer and I think they sould be kept in source code. And, TFS should get this information from source code or from some code. Otherwise, package version will be kept outside the source code. Also, developer should be able to update tfs ci tasks. In my organization it is not allowd. Only configuration team can edit ci tasks.

[image]

So, Is there any way to get major.minor.patch numbers from source code. What is the best practice? In which file version numbers should ve stored and How Tfs should retrieve this information.

Comment: Was this problem ever resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where it was required to copy built files into a folder that contained the version number.

Therefor I created a custom build task in TFS that reads the version from an assembly and stores it into a build variable. Alternatively the custom build task can read the version from a file from source control. (but the you need to maintain this file!)

Let me know in case you need more information.